# 'CommandCursor' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo-3.x

When i run this code ,i get an error 'CommandCursor' object is not subscriptable
pymongo version = 3.3.0

```
try:
    myresults = students.aggregate([{"$unwind":"$scores"},{"$match":{"scores.type":"homework"}},{"$group":{"_id":"$_id","minitem":{"$min":"$scores.score"}}}],useCursor=False)
    for result in myresults['result']:
        scores.update({"_id":result["_id"]},{"$pull":{"scores":{"score": result["minitem"]}}})
except Exception as e:
    raise
```

Answer (score 0):

i removed the result from myresult['result'] and it worked

```
try:
    myresults = students.aggregate([{"$unwind":"$scores"},{"$match":{"scores.type":"homework"}},{"$group":{"_id":"$_id","minitem":{"$min":"$scores.score"}}}],useCursor=False)
    for result in myresults:
        students.update({"_id":result["_id"]},{"$pull":{"scores":{"score": result["minitem"]}}})
except Exception as e:
    raise
```

Answer (score 0):

The aggregate query returns a cursor when useCursor is True, otherwise list. So you should be processing aggregate result by looping through the result.